# time managment software for ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for Task Management or time managment software for ubunutu with features like

- free
- Add tasks easily
- Good user interface
- Save task history

Comment: See also http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Planner](http://live.gnome.org/Planner) - it fulfills your requirements. It is part of the Gnome applications set, and it is available in official Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 1):

After testing everything that was available 2 years ago I ended up using Remember The Milk, even as I don't like web apps. It's just way more usable than everything.
if Evolution is still alive, you may try it. Once it was a close copy of M$ Outlook.